# Count query returning the same result wheather condition matches or not

Tags: count, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am newbie to cakephp 3.2.I have used some query as per the cakephp book,but i am not getting a valid result.I have posted the codes below.Here i want to count some records from database using certain condition.But its returning everytime 1 ,wheather the record is present or not.

```html
  $query = $this->Users->find('all')
                    ->where(['Users.email' => $user->email]);
            $emaildata = $query->select(['count' => $query->func()->count('*')]);
            echo $conter = count($emaildata);//alaways returns 1
```

Please tell me,am i doing anything wrong?Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
echo $counter = $emaildata->count();exit;
```